# Idiom to be used in a situation where someone doesn't want to work, but still does, because one can't survive without earning money

Tags: idioms

In India, when someone doesn't feel like working but still has to, one jokingly uses a Hindi phrase which translates to - "I have to do it for the evil-doer stomach" which implies one can't survive without earning livelihood and to earn that, one has to do work. I'm sure there is an English equivalent of this phrase. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Where I'm from, this phenomenon is often referred to as _life_.

Comment: @oerkelens Where I come from, there is an idiom for this which I described in the question **description**.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija do you mean *paapi pet ka sawaal hai [Hindi]?*

Comment: @SandeepDhamija check the answer down. If you feel the other one better, I'll delete it.

Comment: @MaulikV You don't have to remove it. It's just that I was looking for an equivalent idiom. Not for a translation.

Comment: I never translated it! *there's no stomach in my answer!*

Comment: It doesn't have _spine_ either :)

Comment: Bring home bacon slightly **(I repeat, slightly)** tilts toward the money earned for the family as you bring money home. A responsible person would bring home the bacon. On the other hand if you say something like *earn for living* it means it's the question of your survival first! I don't say it's incorrect but I think if I know Hindi and English equally, earn for living fits better.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija lol. You din' get it. I referred to *stomach* as in Hindi, *pet* comes not *rid (spine)*. Anyway, you may choose D_Bester's answer.

Comment: @MaulikV [Sarcasm](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sarcasm+meaning&oq=sarcasm&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4082j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13727/discussion-between-maulik-v-and-sandeep-dhamija)

Comment: Being a Hindi speaker, I thought I'd understand and try for the closest. Anyway, I deleted my answer as it created a debate than sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite equivalent but try:

> I've got to bring home the bacon.

Unfortunately that will be out of favor in many parts of the world where they don't eat pork, but in the US it means that I have to work so I can feed my family.

Comment: -1 I'm sorry. I'm an Indian and I understand the question better. It's not bringing home the bacon. That Hindi phrase means he's not willing (often forcefully or in negation) to go to job or earn money but there's no any other way to feed the family or himself. You attempted good but I downvoted for the **sole** reason that if a Hindi speakers reads and learns from this answer, they may misinterpret and speak it wrongly.

Comment: @MaulikV An idiom is a combination of words that has a **figurative meaning** owing to its common usage. An idiom's figurative meaning is **separate from the literal meaning**. src- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom

Comment: *Unfortunately that will be out of favor in many parts of the world where they don't eat pork* - true! But there is a solution! In such case, use *bread* instead of *bacon*!

Comment: @MaulikV The "I've got to" means I must; I have no other choice. Not as strong as the original but still can mean I don't want to. It's not a translation and as an idiom it is a good choice; the OP was asking for "where someone doesn't want to work, but still does"; this matches that well.

Comment: @D_Bester true but then it slightly (I repeat, slightly) tilts toward the money earned for the family as you bring money home. A responsible person would bring home the bacon. On the other hand if you say something like *earn for living* it means it's the question of your survival first! I don't say it's incorrect but I think if I know Hindi and English equally, earn for living fits better. Anyway, I leave it on the OP.

Comment: @MaulikV Also: "Bring home the bread" doesn't have the same cachet as "bringing home the bacon"; I've never heard anyone use bread for this phrase.

Comment: @D_Bester vegetarians don't bring bacon to their homes. So, the idiom goes that way. You can replace bacon with anything that a vegetarian eats. Since bread is quite commonly understood, we use 'bread'. It's something like *mankind* is better taken as *humankind* to include women and epicenes! We are not allowed to change the idioms but at times, it's done especially when the users are largely from a special group where some part of idiom does not fit (as here vegetarians).

Comment: @MaulikV I think you are mixing up 'earning the bread' with 'bringing home the bacon'. Idioms are figurative, so there is no question of 'substituting' one word for another. For example take : 'cross the Rubicon'. Just because I am an Indian, I can't make it: 'cross the Ganga'.

Comment: @AdilAli Ganga does not **restrict** anyone to cross it. Bacon **does** -anyway, this is taking long for no reason. Let the OP choose this answer to end it.

Comment: We say for example, 'The early bird gets the worm'. Just because we are not birds or that we do not like worms, we cannot change the idiom!

Answer (score -1):

How about this? :

> I want to quit my job, but I can't, as I have to make both ends meet for my family.

Comment: Family is never a concern. When you say *paapi pet ka sawaal* in Hindi, it's **only you** in fact!

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I was just illustrating the usage of the phrase 'make both ends meet'.

Comment: That **does**. It means that if you don't have family, you probably quit the job! Putting *as...for* you are giving the reason of your helplessness of not quitting job!

Comment: Then I could use, *I want to quit my job, but I can't, as I have to make both ends meet for **me**.*

Comment: @AdilAli: drop "for me" in that case. It's fine (and I'd say preferable) to just say "I have to make both ends meet". You'd only say "for me" if you were in a context like this argument, when you're contrasting it with making ends meet for more than just yourself.

Comment: Oh also, Cambridge dictionary says that "make both ends meet" is specifically Indian English. It makes sense to me with "both" in there, but I'd certainly say just "make ends meet" in British English. So the answer to the question depends who the questioner is planning to say it to :-)